# ng-checked not updating ng-show

Tags: angularjs

In a form I have a checkbox type input that if it is checked should display another section.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkedSeries" ng-checked="expression"> This is part of a series.
<div ng-show="checkedSeries">
     <input type="text"name="inputSeriesTitle" placeholder="Some Title Here">
</div>
```

**When I manually click the checkbox input it works, displaying the field.**

But when using ng-checked="expressionIsTrue" with the checkbox input automatically being checked the model **doesn't seem to update and the extra section is not displayed**.

I think I've done this correctly from the AngularJS docs:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to angular source code :

`// boolean attrs are evaluated
forEach(BOOLEAN_ATTR, function(propName, attrName) {
// binding to multiple is not supported
if (propName == "multiple") return;
function defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr) {
scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
});
}
var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
var linkFn = defaultLinkFn;
if (propName === 'checked') {
linkFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
// ensuring ngChecked doesn't interfere with ngModel when both are set on the same input
if (attr.ngModel !== attr[normalized]) {
defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr);
}
};
}`

Setting ng-checked and ng-model together works, but it doesn't affect ng-model.

So, if you want ng-model and a default value at startup, you can set the value of the checkbox inside your controller :

`$scope.checkedSeries = true;`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` and `ng-checked` don't, and aren't meant to, play well together.  You use `ng-checked` when you just want some visual feedback for the result of an expression, you use `ng-model` when you care about the value of a variable.

It sounds like what you want to do is something more like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkedSeries" ng-init="checkedSeries = expression">
This is part of a series.
<div ng-show="checkedSeries">
     <input type="text"name="inputSeriesTitle" placeholder="Some Title Here">
</div>
```